# Changing colour of Markers - Google Map V2 Android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm having a little trouble understanding how to change the colour of a marker in an Android Google Map project.

My code for a Marker is:

```
googlemap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .position(new LatLng( 65.07213,-2.109375))
    .title("This is my title"))
    .setSnippet("and snippet");
    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ORANGE)));
```

I get this error when I put in the .icon code on the last line, otherwise the `.position`, `.title` and `.setSnippet` work just fine and are visible on the map.

> Cannot invoke icon(BitmapDescriptor) on the primitive type void

These get imported aswell:

```
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptor;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
```

But nothing else is added in. Have I missed a vital part?

Comment: ; means a sentence is over.You finished the sentence before ;.icon

Answer (score 111):

You have a couple of characters wrong there. Compare your code to this:

```
googlemap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .position(new LatLng( 65.07213,-2.109375))
    .title("This is my title")
    .snippet("and snippet")
    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ORANGE)));
```

Removed `)` on third line, changed `setSnippet` to `snippet` and removed `;` on forth line.

Comment: Yes you are correct! it does work. I just got confused with google's example.

Comment: I have set the color with the icon, but then all my markers now have the same color even if i change BitmapDescriptorFactory to a different color.

Comment: shouldn't it be `setIcon`

Answer (score 9):

The problem is the semicolon ";" on the end of the line

```
.setSnippet("and snippet");
```

If you delete the semicolon making it

```
.setSnippet("and snippet")
```

It should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
         .position(new LatLng(19.01062463, 73.01141475))
         .title("Point1").snippet("Speed=1.2")
         .icon(bitmapDescriptorFromVector(context, R.drawable.ic_icon)));
}

googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .position(new LatLng(19.02369039, 73.00778391))
    .title("Point2")
    .snippet("Speed2=0.42").icon(bitmapDescriptorFromVector(context, R.drawable.ic_icon)));
```