# how to change marker colour in google map using colour from colour resource value?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have read some thread to change colour like in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16598709/9101876). but my question is little bit different

I set a marker in google map using the code below

```
googleMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(eventLocation).title("title here")).showInfoWindow()
```

the default marker colour is red, and I need to change that red colour to be the colour that I have in:

resources --> values --> colours

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <color name="brand_color">#78a11d</color>

</resources>
```

how to do that ?

Comment: You cannot do such a thing. The only option would be tint and it will not work here.

Answer (score 0):

May be this can help you

```
mMarkerOptions.position(beachCoord).title("marker title").snippet("marker info").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.gray_dot));
```

In drawable file you can assign a color from color file